# error while connecting to database TypeError: Invalid URL in Mongo DB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-cluster

When  I am trying to connect mongo db cluster with my application it is showing this error
[image]

I am using URL for Node.js driver of version `2.2.12` or higher

Here is the code of my `db.js` file

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose'; //mongoose library is used to form connection between your application and your database mongodb could also be used for the same

const Connection = async () => {
  const URL = `mongodb://chirag_79:myCorrectPasswords@ac-jqvhtzt-shard-00-00.nt4mr7j.mongodb.net:27017,ac-jqvhtzt-shard-00-01.nt4mr7j.mongodb.net:27017,ac-jqvhtzt-shard-00-02.nt4mr7j.mongodb.net:27017/?ssl=true&replicaSet=atlas-mbzzwi-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(URL, { useNewUrlParser: true }); //connect function takes two arguments one is the URL and another one is to save us from the error of old urlParser being deprecated
    //old URL parser is deprecated so we will use a new URL parser
    console.log('database connected successfully');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`error while connecting to database ${error}`);
  }
};

export default Connection;
```

Here is the URL to my mongo db cluster: `mongodb://chirag_79:myCorrectPasswords@ac-jqvhtzt-shard-00-00.nt4mr7j.mongodb.net:27017,ac-jqvhtzt-shard-00-01.nt4mr7j.mongodb.net:27017,ac-jqvhtzt-shard-00-02.nt4mr7j.mongodb.net:27017/?ssl=true&replicaSet=atlas-mbzzwi-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority`

Answer (score 0):

**The issue was in the password**

if you'll use special characters as the password and pass them as it is in the URL then it will create issues.

I changed my password and the problem got fixed.